# SQL select aggregate values in columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in this structure:

```
editor_id
rev_user
rev_year
rev_month
rev_page
edit_count
```

here is the sqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cbb1/1

I need to surface the 5 most active editors during March 2011 for example - i.e. for each rev_user - sum all of the edit_count for each rev_month and rev_year to all of the rev_pages.

Any suggestions how to do it?

UPDATE -
updated fiddle with demo data

Comment: please specify your records in sql fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this:

- Select the total using `SUM` and `GROUP BY`, filtering by `rev_year` and `rev_month`
- Order by the `SUM` in descending order
- Limit the results to the top five items

Here is how:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT rev_user, SUM(edit_count) AS total_edits
    FROM edit_count_user_date
    rev_year='2006' AND rev_month='09'
    GROUP BY rev_user
) x
ORDER BY total_edits DESC
LIMIT 5
```

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cbb1/3)

Comment: OK Thanks, now if I need to provide list of rev_pages edited by the most active editor, along with the number of editing acts he has invested at each document.
i.e. I need to find the most active editor (sum 'edit_count' of rev_page of each year and month) and then find all the pages he edited. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is as straightforward as :

```
SELECT rev_user, SUM(edit_count) as TotalEdits
FROM edit_count_user_date
WHERE rev_month = 'March' and rev_year = '2014'
GROUP BY rev_user
ORDER BY TotalEdits DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/489456/2)

May I also suggest using a more appropriate `DATE` type for the year and month storage?

**Edit, re new Info**

The below will return all edits for the given month for the 'highest' `MonthTotal` editor, and then re-group the totals by the `rev_page`.

```
SELECT e.rev_user, e.rev_page, SUM(e.edit_count) as TotalEdits
FROM edit_count_user_date e
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT rev_user, rev_year, rev_month, SUM(edit_count) AS MonthTotal
  FROM edit_count_user_date
  WHERE rev_month = '09' and rev_year = '2010'
  GROUP BY rev_user, rev_year, rev_month
  ORDER BY MonthTotal DESC
  LIMIT 1
) as x
ON e.rev_user = x.rev_user AND e.rev_month = x.rev_month AND e.rev_year = x.rev_year
GROUP BY e.rev_user, e.rev_page;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1cf80d/3) - I've adjusted the data to make it more interesting.
However, if you need to do this across several months at a time, it will be more difficult given MySql's lack of `partition by` / analytical [windowing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function).

Comment: OK Thanks, now if I need to provide list of rev_pages edited by the most active editor, along with the number of editing acts he has invested at each document.
i.e. I need to find the most active editor (sum 'edit_count' of rev_page of each year and month) and then find all the pages he edited. how can I do it?

Comment: I've updated for one month, although see the caveat if you intend doing this across multiple months in one go.